# Second installation of Wordpress without a new database, with the first one already working

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress installation in Italian. Now I'd like to have the site multi-language, adding an English version. The website is run by Wordpress, but I customized it so much that every translation plug-in fails. And I can't re-install the original Wordpress (yes, I read to change table prefix on the second installation, but it seems I had to take care of it before the first installation).

I thought to move just the ftp files on another subdirectory, leaving these files picking data from the same database (in fact, dynamic content is not different, what changes is the static interface).

Would it be enough to clone the existing installation and paste it into a new directory of the website to make a second website work? In this case, I could slowly edit the second website's interface, translating it step by step.

Answer (score 1):

Use Wordpress Importer plugin then export your data, delete database and file, after re-install WP in the language you want, and re-use the same plugin to import data on the new installation... I made this, it works great!